# Error:Build-in class shrinker and multidex are not supported yet

Tags: android, android-build, android-build-type

After adding `useProguard  true` and `multidexEnabled true` to my built types this error comes up when trying to build:

> Error:Build-in class shrinker and multidex are not supported yet.

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.android
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode gitVersionCode()
    versionName gitVersionName()
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        ...
        useProguard false
        debuggable true
    }
    release {
        ...
        useProguard true
    }
```

Running Android Studio 2.0 Beta 5.

Any solution besides removing multidex?

Comment: I am having the same problem. replacing useProguard with minifyEnabled and building multiple times made by app build successfully again..

Comment: I had the same error message on AS2.2. In my case, removing all "useProguard" and replacing it with "minifyEnabled" fixed the issue. According to the http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType.html, "useProguard" no longer exists.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`useProguard` became `minifyEnabled`. Try the following:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone is still looking into this.
First of all, try to avoid the 64k limit (and avoid using multiDexEnabled) by enable code shrinking. Try the following:

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

If the above doesn't work and you have to use miltiDexEnabled then don't use proguard and don't try to shrink resources. Try the following:

```
buildTypes {
    ...
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply disable shrinkResources, and multiDexEnable, it solved the problem.

```
shrinkResources false
multiDexEnabled false
```

Also, disable dex option false if you have dexoption as below:

```
dexOptions {
        incremental false
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

just remove multidexEnabled and use progaurd from there and give it a try.

Comment: I want to have multidex enabled due to the 64K limit.

Comment: @powder366 if you use proguard, you won't need to enable multidex for 64k limit ;)